# Allocate Spatial Lines inside surrounding Spatial Polygons

Tags: r, spatial, geo, r-sp

I’m having trouble with an application in R that uses georreferenced data at the street (zip code) level. I tried to write a script that mimics my problem in a simple way so it’s easier to take suggestions. I’m also relative new in R, so I’m sorry if the question is too simple or too impossible.

I have some data, lets say crimes, that are associated with zip codes from a city. Besides that, my application is working with census tract from this same city, so I need to allocate a value of crimes from a street (zip code) to Census Tracts surrounding this street.

Streets are modeled as SpatialLinesDataFrames, while Census Tracts are SpatialPolygonsDataFrames, from package sp. The problems are: (1) streets have two sides (two sidewalks) and each side might contains homes placed inside different Census Tracts; (2) some census tracts are bigger than a single block, so, in this case, both sides of the streets (both sidewalks) are inside the same Census Tract.

I’m thinking about dividing the crime value of a street to each Census Tract surrounding it in the same proportion as the length of the sidewalks inside that Census Tract. Implicit assumption is that a crime has the same probability of happening in every meter of the sidewalks.

In the script that follows I have three census tracts - A (green), B (yellow) and C (red) – and one street (blue line).

- The street has 3 units of length (6 if both sidewalks are considered), while each census tract has only 1 units of length.
- Census Tract A (green) contains both sides of the sidewalk, so I need to allocate 2/6 of the crimes committed in that street to this Census Tract;
- Census Tract B (yellow) contains only one sidewalk of length 1, so it should be allocated with 1/6 of the crimes;
- Census Tract C (red) is like the former, it contains one sidewalk of length 1 and should be allocated with 1/6 of the crimes;
- The remaining 2/6 of the crimes are outside those census tracts, so I don’t need to allocate them anywhere (or I’ll allocate in neighboring Census Tracts).

Here is the script...

```
library(sp)


# Definig SpatialLinesDataFrame of streets (zipcodes)
slin <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(x=c(3,3), y=c(5,2)))),"street")))
sldf <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(slin, data.frame(crime=10, row.names="street"))

# Definig SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of Census Tract A, B and C
spol <- SpatialPolygons(list(
Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x=c(2,4,4,2), y=c(4,4,3,3)))),"A"),
Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x=c(2,3,3,2), y=c(3,3,2,2)))),"B"),
Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x=c(3,4,4,3), y=c(3,3,2,2)))),"C")))

spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spol, data.frame(crime=c(0,0,0), row.names=c("A","B","C")))

plot(spdf, col=c("green","yellow","red"),ylim=c(1,5))
lines(sldf, col="blue", lwd=3)
```

The question is how can I implement it?

I figured a function intersect() from package raster that seems to break the street into smaller segments to fit inside each Census Tract, but I still have no idea on how to deal with the cases where each sidewalk belongs to a different Census Tract.

I welcome any help, and, if necessary, I can provide more information on what is needed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My recommendation would be to look at `sf::st_relate` to pull out the relationship between your streets and tracts.

Comment: Nice @jsta , I think sf::st_relate will really help me. I trying to build a script with st_intersection and st_relate. I am still struggling with the algorithms, but, if I have any specific question, I will bring it up here again. Thanks a lot